# Angular Set Input Cursor to next input, PS: next input tag will be dynamically added on keyEnter of previous input click

Tags: javascript, python, angular, typescript

I am using a for loop with input tags. User inputs something and on enter press the command is submitted and the current for loop is pushed with another input tag. I want the cursor to be moved to next input. There are many solutions out there where getting the srcElement and moving focus to next Element but here next element is added dynamically.

**shell.component.html**

```
<div class="shell">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let text of shellText">
            <ng-container *ngIf="getType(text['type']);else input">
                <td style="width: 2%">{{text['preText']}}</td>
                <td>{{text['text']}}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #input>
                <td style="width: 2%">{{text['preText']}}</td>
                <td><input [readonly]="text['type'] == 'command'" class="shell-input"
                        (keyup.enter)="onEnter($event,text['line'])" [(ngModel)]="text['text']" mat-input type="text" /></td>
            </ng-template>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

**shell.component.ts**

```
  onEnter(event, line) {
    if (this.shellText[line - 1].text.trim().endsWith(':')) {
      this.shellText.push({ 'type': CLASSES['CONTINUE_COMMAND'], 'line': line + 1, 'preText': '', 'text': '    ' },)
    } else {
      this.shellText.push({ 'type': CLASSES['CURRENT_COMMAND'], 'line': line + 1, 'preText': '>>>', 'text': '' },)
    }
    this.shellText[line - 1]['type'] = CLASSES['COMMAND']

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setFocus(event)
    }, 2000);
  }


  setFocus(event) {
    debugger
    let element = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling; // get the sibling element
    console.log(element)
    if (element == null)  // check if its null
      return;
    else
      element.focus();   // focus if not null
  }
```

**Note: I am trying to create a python shell**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**shell.component.ts**

```
  setFocusevent) {
    let element = event.srcElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.lastElementChild.firstElementChild; // get the sibling element
    if (element == null)  // check if its null
      return;
    else
      element.focus();   // focus if not null
  }
```

1. You first get the reference of the `<input>`tag
2. Then you get its parent element which is `<td>`
3. Then you go further up to `<tr>`
4. Then you reference to the next `<tr>` which will be dynamically created
5. Then you access the last element which will be that last `<td>`
6. Then you point to your desired `<input>` element and add focus

Comment: well it worked great.. I had to use jquery to solve the problem.